# NOT LIKE ANY query in Snowflake

Tags: sql-like, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the following query in Snowflake:

```
SELECT * FROM chapters 
WHERE
title NOT LIKE ANY ('Summary%', 'Appendix%')
```

but it errors out. I know Snowflake support LIKE ANY query syntax. But I am not sure why my query is not working.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It does seem like that syntax with NOT should work, and I'm not quite sure why it doesn't, but this works.

```
SELECT * FROM chapters 
WHERE
NOT (title LIKE ANY ('Summary%', 'Appendix%'))
```

Extra parens are optional, but seems more clear to me when it's "worded" this way.

Answer (score 1):

The query execution looks like this when we see the profile for the below query.

```
select cc_name from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCDS_SF100TCL"."CALL_CENTER"
where not(cc_name  like any ('North%', 'Califor%'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports function version of syntax for [LIKE ANY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like_any).

```
SHOW FUNCTIONS LIKE 'LIKE_ANY';
```

| name | min_num_arguments | max_num_arguments | arguments | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LIKE_ANY | 3 | -1 | LIKE_ANY(VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR) | RETURN BOOLEAN returns TRUE if subject LIKE any of the patterns |

The signature is as follows:

<sub>* as the moment of writing there is no documentation webpage</sub>

```
LIKE_ANY(subject, escape_character, pattern1, pattern2, ...)
```

---

For query in question the equivalent is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM chapters 
WHERE NOT LIKE_ANY(title, '!', 'Summary%', 'Appendix%');
```

Input data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE chapters(title TEXT) AS 
SELECT 'Summary' UNION 
SELECT 'Addendum' UNION
SELECT 'Appendix 1';
```

Output:

[image]